# How to return general purpose pointers in a c function?

Tags: c, pointers

I have seen this kind of syntax:

```c
void *job(void *arg){
   //does something, no return type
}
```

This notation can be used like in an other way:

```c
void *method = job;
```

So it seems you can use this notation to write something like this faster:

```c
void job(void *arg){ //no pointer here
   //does something, no return type
}
...
void *method = *job;
```

But then I am wondering how to express that a method shall actually return a general purpose pointer?
What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> void *job(void *arg){
>    //does something, no return type
> }
> ```

as to return a `void*`,  *no return type* is false

`void` and `void*` and different

> This notation can be used like in an other way:
>
> void *method = job;

this is not the correct way if you want to say you save a pointer to the function *job*, must be `void *(*method)(void) = job;`

`void *method = *job;` is wrong, if you use the option -pedantic you will have the error `ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]`

I encourage you to ask for the high level of warning/error, if you use *gcc* do *gcc -pedantic -Wextra* for instance

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. What is the reason this question got downvoted so much?